# firebase messaging: image not displaying via payload in android

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

firebase messaging image not displaying via payload in android but it is working fine in iOS

```
I/FirebaseMessaging( 1559): Starting download of: https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/252-2524695_dummy-profile-image-jpg-hd-png-download.png

W/FirebaseMessaging( 1559): Failed to download image: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/252-2524695_dummy-profile-image-jpg-hd-png-download.png
```

here is my payload

```
{
    "message": {
        "token": "fh748hf......",
        "notification": {
            "body": "This is an FCM notification message!",
            "title": "FCM Message"
        },
        "data": {
            "body": "This is an FCM notification message!",
            "title": "FCM Message"
        },
        "android": {
            "notification": {
                "image": "https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/252-2524695_dummy-profile-image-jpg-hd-png-download.png"
            }
        },
        "apns": {
            "payload": {
                "aps": {
                    "mutable-content": 1
                }
            },
            "fcm_options": {
                "image": "https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/252-2524695_dummy-profile-image-jpg-hd-png-download.png"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below command returns 403 Forbidden.

```
curl -v https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/252-2524695_dummy-profile-image-jpg-hd-png-download.png --output image.png
```

After adding user agent the download succeeded.

```
curl -v --user-agent "foobar"  https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/252-2524695_dummy-profile-image-jpg-hd-png-download.png --output image.png
```

Worth of trying.